# Transfer data in silverlight in modal windows

Tags: silverlight, modal-window

How do I transfer data from one window to another modal in silverlight. I have one window, push the button and another window appears where complements sample text boxes, data from these fields I would like to have seen in the previous window.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what type of framework you're using. In caliburn micro with a viewmodel first approach these types of things are very simple. You just create a new viewmodel and set the proper fields and let caliburn handle displaying it for you. With other view first approaches it is more difficult. You can maybe use a Message to set the fields using something like MVVM Light. Either way we need more information on how you are building your app to answer your question.